# What tags should we use for the "When They Cry" franchise?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have three tags related to the "When they Cry" franchise: [when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/when-they-cry), [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni), and [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni). Are all three of these necessary? And if not, which should we keep, and what synonyms should we use?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion we do not need all three tags.

There is very little in common between Higurashi and Umineko. The characters are almost entirely different, and the plots are basically unrelated. Almost all the in-universe questions that make sense to ask are specific to one or the other. Plenty of people (including to some degree myself) are an expert on one but not the other. Wikipedia doesn't even have a real entry for the series; [what they have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_They_Cry) is a disambiguation page pointing to Higurashi and Umineko. Hence, we should probably have different tags for the two.

As for whether we need a third tag for the series as a whole, this seems unnecessary right now. It's not prohibitive to just use tags for both Higurashi and Umineko for the few questions about the series as a whole. More importantly, this tag risks being used on questions which are specific to one or the other, like [What exactly are the rollbacks in Higurashi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/181/what-exactly-are-the-rollbacks-in-higurashi). If that happens, this tag will be the most used, which will be bad for SEO since "Higurashi" and "Umineko" are likely to be the most common search terms. If the franchise expands significantly it might eventually be necessary, but for now such a tag is counterproductive and harmful to SEO.

As for what tags to use, all things being equal we should prefer the English language version of the names. The most common search terms are just "Higurashi" and "Umineko" which will be caught by either the English or Japanese titles. Hence we should use [higurashi-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-when-they-cry) and [umineko-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-when-they-cry). Synonyms should be made for the Japanese names [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni) and [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni).

**tl;dr**:

- Add [higurashi-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-when-they-cry) with synonym [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni).
- Add [umineko-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-when-they-cry) with synonym [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni).
- Kill [when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/when-they-cry). Questions about the series should be tagged with both [higurashi-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-when-they-cry) and [umineko-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-when-they-cry).

Comment: Ah a 2013 answer. What about now in [2022 with gou sotsu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD0PuYzJm88) and [ciconia](https://www.reddit.com/r/umineko/comments/tfg4kq/ryukishi07_stated_that_her_similarity_to_was/)?

Answer (score -1):

**Keep all three tags.**

- [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni) is specific to Higurashi (WTC1-2)
- [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni) is specific to Umineko (WTC3-4)
- [when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/when-they-cry) is for overlapping parts of the franchise

The Umineko sound novels provide some further insight into the workings of some parts of Higurashi, and therefore [What exactly are the rollbacks in Higurashi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/181/what-exactly-are-the-rollbacks-in-higurashi) probably could not be explained fully without knowledge gained from Umineko, despite it being a question about Higurashi. This is why it is tagged [when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/when-they-cry) - this is a question about overlapping parts of the franchise.

If they are so unrelated as Logan M's answer claims, then why has the creator given them not only similar Japanese titles but also series-like English titles?

Not sure if this is worth nothing, but it is rumored that WTC5 is in the works to some degree already.

Comment: If the question is about Higurashi, but the answer involves information from Umineko, then the question should only be tagged with Higurashi. Tags are supposed to be attributes of the question, not the answer(s).

Comment: As for the titling, I don't know why they are so similar, but IMO that's stylistic and not incredibly substantial. I also don't know why the "Final Fantasy" games are all titled similarly despite being mostly unrelated plotwise. The English titles are translated from the Japanese ones so the fact that both are similar doesn't really have any extra meaning. However, if the they are so closely related (which, having read all of the kinetic novels, I disagree with), we should have one tag, not two. Three is redundant no matter how you slice it.

Comment: @LoganM It seems like almost all of our identification requests are tagged with the answer though - http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request

Comment: Yes, that's something which should probably stop. It was discussed at http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/435/should-we-add-a-series-tag-to-identification-questions-that-have-accepted-answer. Unfortunately a lot of people are still doing it, and in my opinion it's not really worth it to revert those edits.

Comment: This aged well in [2022 with gou sotsu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD0PuYzJm88) and [ciconia](https://www.reddit.com/r/umineko/comments/tfg4kq/ryukishi07_stated_that_her_similarity_to_was/)!