# Can we reverse the direction of the synonym between the tags [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni] and [higurashi-when-they-cry]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni) is the parent tag, and it has the synonym [higurashi-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-when-they-cry). Can we reverse the direction of the synonym to make the parent tag as the one with the English title? I think this would be in line with the [current policy](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2021-policy-review-how-do-we-want-to-name-series-tags).

If reversing the direction of the synonym is appropriate in this case, can it also be done for the tag [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni), which is a tag for [another installment in the series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-tags-should-we-use-for-the-when-they-cry-franchise), having the synonym [umineko-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-when-they-cry)? I believe it is natural to treat the two cases identically, hence combining both requests into a single Meta post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** Both [higurashi-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-when-they-cry) and [umineko-when-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-when-they-cry) are now the main tags, with [higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni) and [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni) as their synonym.